# custom, emitted events (handling) - vueJS

Tags: vue.js

Im new to VueJS.
I'm trying to understand the syntax behind emitting events. 
There is the following video tutorial where I'm having problems understanding what happens:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pvG6fzkdFM

Here is the code:

Inside parent:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVkJl.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/107yS.jpg

And Child (emitting component):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSuTL.jpg

Now, the first thing I very much DONT understand is how the "v-on:CustomEvent" actually works. 
v-on, as I understand it, attaches an event handler. But it doesnt specify it, does it? I usually have to type "v-on:click". So why does anything happen at all in this tutorial when this code is executed? Nowhere is there a definition what kind of event shall trigger the function.

And the second thing is how the data is handled. 
In the header, inside the parameter of the function, $event is handed over. 
But how is this supposed to give any useful data? The event usually is an object where I have to get the payload extracted manually, like event.target.value?
So why does this work?

Comment: Try the below one, your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine, there is no fix needed

Alternate way is, no need to mention $event, it automatically pass with the arguments by just mentioning the method name

```
<app-header v-bind:title="title" v-on:changeTitle="updateTitle"></app-header>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer!
But my problem wasnt that the code wasnt working, its just from a tutorial in the end. 
My problem is that I dont understand how the vue syntax works. 
Why does v-on:customEvent actually fire? No action which triggers the event (e.g. click, change etc.) was defined. That was the main part of my question.

Comment: When you want to send data from parent to child you can use props. If you want to pass data from child to parent, you need events or store or root vue instance data properties to pass values from Child. In your are case it is not a click or change event. But internally you can use vue advantage and create a custom event and handle the event from parent. Using this approach, you can create dynamic components and communication across components.

Comment: Yes, but how does the event know when to fire? THAT was my question. There is no event specified when it fires, theres just the denominator of the function to call, but not the case WHEN to call it.

Comment: The event will not get fired until and unless you use this.$emit('changeTitle', 'title'),. This is a programatic  way to trigger a event. You can use it in computed or watchers or in html inline to when to perform